# return the first Book object written by an author with this first name in Array?

Tags: java, arrays, bluej, getmethod

Hi sorry beginner coder here and I am not good at explaining things very well but I was wondering  how do I return the first book object of an Array?

Here is my code:

```
public Book getBookWrittenBy(String firstName){
    Book writtenBy = null;

    if((inventory == null) || (inventory.length == 0)){
        return null;
    }
    for(int i=0; i < inventory.length; i++){
        if(inventory[i] != null && writtenBy == null || inventory[i].getTitle().equals(firstName)){
            writtenBy = inventory[i];
        }

    }
    return writtenBy;
}
```

When I test this code on BlueJ compiler it returns a title from the Author but not the First instance of the `Book` object with the `firstName`.

Here is the method I need to use:

`public Book getBookWrittenBy(String firstName)`

- returns the first `Book` object written by an author with this first name

If any one can help me code this that would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Something fishy in the jungle here. Post the Book class and how you are Declaring and filling the so called inventory[] array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following solution:

```
public Book getBookWrittenBy(String firstName){
    if((inventory == null) || (inventory.length == 0)){
        return null;
    }
    for(int i=0; i < inventory.length; i++){
        if(inventory[i] != null && inventory[i].getTitle().equals(firstName)){
            return inventory[i];
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

You can simply return inventory[i]; This will exit the for-loop implicit and return the first instance of a book.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but when I do this it returns a null

Comment: please add System.out.println("Some text") before every "return null;" To see which one is used.. You can use a debugger thou.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different layout. When you exit the method early on exceptional inputs, it helps debugging the code and makes the loop easier to understand. Using a for each loop simplifies your code as well.

```
interface Book {
  String getFirstNameOfAuthor()
  String getLastNameOfAuthor()
}

public Book getBookWrittenBy(Book[] inventory, String firstName) {
  if (null == inventory || null == firstName) return null;

  for (Book book : inventory) {
    if (firstName.equals(book.getFirstName)) return book;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion but I can't use a for each loop I must use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you just put the return statement inside the for cycle you'll return at the first occurence what you find. Your way, you're returning the last one you find, because you assign a new book written by that author to the variable writtenBy every time you find one. Try to rewrite the for cycle:

```
for(int i=0; i < inventory.length; i++){
if(inventory[i].getTitle().equals(firstName))
    return inventory[i];
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion but when i do this it still returns any book from the author what I need is to return is the first book on my Array from the author.

Comment: Are you sure you replaced your for cycle with this one? It seems strange to me, this one should return the first result in the array.

Comment: Hi yes I did what happens is it returns the first element of the Array and not the first book of the author firstName

Comment: Probably you didn't remove the first OR part in the if check: the first part is actually saying that if you find a book that is not null and writtenBy is still null (and you initialize it at null) you enter the if check and then return that element. Try to remove it and just leave this condition: `if(inventory[i].getTitle().equals(firstName))`

Comment: Yes I have exactly what you have right now and I deleted the writtenBy local variable but when I do this it askes me for a return statement when I leave the writtenBy local variable it returns the first element.

Comment: Thanks btw I really appreciate all this help

Comment: You have to leave a return statement out of the "if" checks, because in case you skip all the ifs you must have something to return. Add a "return null" statement at the end of the method, in case you found nothing in for loop.

Comment: Yes I tried return null; but when I do this it returns null instead of the title

Comment: Did you added the return statement AFTER the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid returning `null` and it will be better to use `Optional` class.

So your solution could look like:

```
public Optional<Book> getBookWrittenBy(String firstname) {
    return Stream.of(inventory)
        .filter(book -> firstname.equals(book.getAuthor()))
        .findFirst();
```